# DB::ParsingException: Cannot parse input: expected ']' before: 'json'

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I need to parse a message from kafka to clickhouse version 22.8.1.1
The message is a single json array

```
[
    {
        "partner_id":156,
        "id":"bc238532-e400-786c-1e86-c821b49776fd",
        "type":4,
        "remove":0,
        "segments":[
        "M103zyb0n0000054"
        ]
    }
]
```

In documentation says that I could use JsonAsString format. So I create table with kafka engine:

```
CREATE TABLE testdb.queue_json (
        `message` String
) 
ENGINE = Kafka 
SETTINGS 
        kafka_broker_list = 'xxx', 
        kafka_topic_list = 'mytopic', 
        kafka_group_name = 'mygroup1', 
        kafka_format = 'JSONAsString',
        kafka_max_block_size = 1048576
```

But got parsing exception:

```
<Error> void DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(size_t): Code: 27. DB::ParsingException: Cannot parse input: expected ']' before: '{"partner_id": 156, "id": "9e8c4e5b-2468-be69-3d3b-43e1a6eb28f5", "type": 4, "remove": 0, "segments": ["M103zyb0n0000054"]}, {"partner_id": 156, "id": "6897d272': while parsing Kafka message ... (CANNOT_PARSE_INPUT_ASSERTION_FAILED)
```

Comment: You JSON has mis-matched square brackets (or is that just a typo?)

Comment: @RichRaposa, it's just a typo. The main point is I cant pars array of jsons, but according to docs it should work:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats#jsonasstring

Comment: Your data looks like an array of values. Try making message an Array(String)

Comment: @RichRaposa, I recieve data from kafka and dont have permission for changes, so i need to parse array of jsons. And docs says I should use JSONAsString, but it doesn't work and I dont know why

Comment: I don't know why JSONAsString is so important, but my comment is to try the following:
CREATE TABLE testdb.queue_json (
        `message` Array(String)
) 
ENGINE = Kafka

Comment: @RichRaposa Oh I see. But the point is I cant read data from kafka and get ParsingException when I try to use some of many jsons format. But I need JSONAsString to use JsonExtract in future. Ps I can read messages from kafka as strings so the raw will look like "[{json}, {json}]", but for my task it's useless

Comment: DId you try CREATE TABLE testdb.queue_json (
        `message` Array(JSON)
)

Comment: @RichRaposa No, I dont understand what type of kafka_format I should use then

Comment: I feel like you should have Array(String) as the column data type in your CH table, and kafka_format is JSONEachRow.

Comment: @RichRaposa It didnt work. The main problem is that clickhouse cant read message from kafka in json formats and throw DB::ParsingException: Cannot parse input: expected ']' before: '{...